# Twitter api not display following count

Tags: php, api, twitter

I want to get total number of following count in twitter using `TwitterAPIExchange` API but the result does not contain following data.
How can i do this any idea?

The followers_count and friends_count are availabel but not following_count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for follower counter:

```
    <?php 


    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php'); //https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

    /** Access token (https://dev.twitter.com/apps/) **/

    $access_token_settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
            'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
            'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    );

    $twitter_api_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
    $getfield = '?screen_name=YOUR SCREEN NAME';
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($access_token_settings);
    $follow_count=$twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($twitter_api_url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
    $data = json_decode($follow_count, true);
    $followers_count=$data[0]['user']['followers_count'];
    echo $followers_count;
?>
```

For parsing data into xml format you can use following code:

```
<?php 
    $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement(urlencode(strip_tags('https://twitter.com/users/google.xml')), null, true);
    echo "Follower count: ".$xml_data->followers_count;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want following counts not followers count